# Removing empty Input Elements from a form

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I have a simple form that goes on to create all the form and validation requirements for codeigniter.  What I want to do is filter out any empty inputs prior to serialization so that I do not create form inputs and form validation set rules. I am at a loss as to how to go about this. Where I have the alert in the Jquery is where I want to remove any empty inputs(again prior to serialization). **At this point what I am using does not detect empty form fields.** Without the detection code the entire system works fine. Here is what I am using

```
    <h1>Field Name</h1>
    <form action="Form.php" onsubmit="return false;" id="form" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="v1" id="v1" /> 
    <input type="text" name="v2" id="v2" /> 
    <input type="text" name="v3" id="v3" /> 
    <input type="text" name="v4" id="v4" /> 
    <input type="text" name="v5" id="v5" /> 
    <input type="text" name="v6" id="v6" /> 

<input type="submit" name="send" id="send" value="Send" />
        </form>
<hr />
<script>
$(function(){
$('#send').click(function(){ 
---------------------------------------   
    $(":input").each(function() {
    if($(this).val() === "")
    alert("Empty Fields!!"); //using alert just to see if empty fields are detected.
    return false;
});
-----------------------------------------
var data = $('#form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        url: "Form.php",
        success: function(msg){
             if(msg){
                $('#display').html(msg).show();
             }else{
                $('#display').text("<p>nothing came back</p>");
             }
        }       
    });
return false;    
});
});
```

I am simply trying to avoid printing out empty form fields

```
<p>
<label for=""></label> <br />
<input type="text" name="" id="" /> <br />
<label class="error" id=""> This field is required</label> <br />
<p/>
```

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will remove all the text fields which have a value of length 0:

```
$('#send').click(function(){ 
$(':input[type="text"]').filter(function(e){
    if (this.value.length===0){
      return true;
    }  
}).remove();
    });
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/ZBSyX/

Comment: it removes the elements that are empty as it should, now I just have to figure out what to do with the (not shown here) $v1 = $_post['v1'] that is now throwing an error :)  thanks!

Comment: `if (isset($_POST['v1'])){ $v1 = $_POST['v1']; }` and if you intend to do that 9 times, then by all means put it in a for loop.

Comment: Yes and just use one 3 line  template for all.  I understand. Again thanks to everyone

Answer (score 1):

You should use a regex expression using \s as the search query. So /^(\s)*$/ as the regex and just make sure input does not match this.

Sorry but I am not familiar with Jquery or I would write the code out exactly.

Comment: jQuery doesn't work that way; you can't put a regular expression in a selector [(not out of the box, anyway)](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/).

Answer (score 1):

```
    $('#send').click(function(){ 
//---------------------------------------   
    $(":input").each(function() {
    if($(this).val() === "")
    alert("Empty Fields!!"); //using alert just to see if empty fields are detected.
    return false;
});
```

And you're not getting an error from this? The first lambda's scope isn't closed.

Use Firebug to highlight errors that you might be getting and post those.

Comment: This should, I think, be a comment to the question itself, rather than an answer. Albeit it's difficult to coherently post this much code in a comment...

Comment: Its ok with me if its an answer, he did ask me to post more data, I appreciate the effort

Answer (score 1):

To hide elements that have no `value` assigned:

```
$('input:text[value=""]').hide();
```

But, of course, if a `value="x"` attribute is provided in the html this will result in the element being shown.