# Rails remove params from rendered form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have a form in a page, with submit button.
Form contains some inputs.
When user press sumbit button, he gets so link:

```
/top?user_id=67508&country=&state=&city=&mode=0&page=19
```

How to remove empty params, user should not see it - country, city, state in this example

params.delete :country - don't works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot stop any parameters from being submitted from the client by using ruby code. This could easily be solved through Javascript by listening to the `submit` event of the form, and attaching a handler to this event which filters the parameters.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20390861/filter-form-parameters-before-submitting) for an example.

Comment: Sure, I'd be happy to!

Comment: Can you join here ? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50211/room-for-arup-rakshit-and-phrogz