# remove all blank inputs with jquery?

Tags: jquery

How can I clean up my webpage by removing the blank inputs within list items?

I have:

```
<li><input type="text"></li>

$('li:empty').remove();    
$('input:empty').remove();
```

This doesn't work because the input:empty is wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing empty Input Elements from a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269249/removing-empty-input-elements-from-a-form)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `input` you should check `value` length:

```js
$('li:empty').remove();
$('input').each(function() {
  if ($(this).val() === '') {
    $(this).remove();
  }
});
//or
$('input[value=""]').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="" />
<input type="text" value="DO NOT DELETE" />

<ul>
  <li>DO NOT DELETE</li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```